# Using inet postgres datatype with OpenJPA

Tags: java, postgresql, openjpa

My application is using OpenJPA to connect with a Postgres database. In the schema I am using the inet postgres datatype in a column. This field in Java is a String. I am able to read the field correctly, but I am having problems inserting a new row.

Searching on the Internet I have found three possible solutions to do this:

1. Creating a Native query. This method works, but in my specific case creating a Native query in order to insert this row implies creating more queries that were being managed by OpenJPA which can lead to lots of bugs. So it is not the more suitable solution in this case.
2. Creating a PostgresDictionary like in this question: [How to use Postgres inet data type with OpenJPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707206/how-to-use-postgres-inet-data-type-with-openjpa). I have implemented this exactly how this user explains. I have created the custom PostgresDictionary, I have added the columnDefinition in the @Column annotation and I have added the property in the persistence.xml. But my custom PostgresDictionary is never called.
   When the application created the PostgresDictionary keeps creating the org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.PostgresDictionary instead of the custom one.
3. Implementing a custom Strategy, like this example http://webspherepersistence.blogspot.co.at/2009/04/custom-orm-with-openjpa.html. But in order to implement the Strategy, I have to set the type of the column from the class java.sql.Types (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html?is-external=true) and there is no inet type in this column. I tried Types.OTHER, but I still have the same error indicating that the column is a type inet and the value I am trying to insert is varchar (String).

So, does anybody has an idea how to fix the problem I am having with the mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in the point 2 was not working because the openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary was been overiden by the class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaVendorAdapter that had the database property set to POSTGRESQL. Which aparently set the DBDictionary to org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.PostgresDictionary independently of the value set in the persistence.xml property.

Deleting this database property from the OpenJpaVendorAdapter allowed me to use my custom PostgresDictionary.